# Visual Studio wrongly shows missing references

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm using VS 2019 v16.11.7 and am having issues which surface after a few debugging sessions.  As seen in the picture below, it starts highlighting code which it thinks is missing references.  Yet the code compiles fine.  I have to close, then reopen VS to clear the problem.  It will come back after a number of debugging sessions.

[image: VS Errors]

Comment: I have seen this before, but very rarely. Maybe the intellisense cache is corrupted. Try a clean build.